Geometry Problem on Congruent Triangles and Angle Chasing
Okay so the question is:
In the diagram below, $\overline{\text{AD}} \cong \overline{\text{BC}}$ and $\alpha + \beta = 180^\circ$ (diagram not to scale). Find the measure
of $\theta$.
We also get this information.
Hint: First extend $\overline{\text{DC}}$ past C to the point E where $\overline{\text{CE}} \cong \overline{\text{AB}}$, then draw $\overline{\text{AE}}$ and look for
congruent triangles.
We are given this picture:

So first I extended $\overline{\text{DC}}$ to the right and made the new line segment be the same size as $\overline{\text{AB}}$. Then I drew a line down from point "A" to make a new triangle. This new point I called "E".

Now I wrote down what I know up to this point.
AD = BC,
$\alpha + \beta = 180^\circ$ (we know because of Alternate (interior) angles)
$\beta$ + $m\angle$ECA = 180$^\circ$ (we know this because angles on a straight line have to equal 180 degrees)
So this is where I get stuck on. I think I am supposed to focus on $\angle$BCA but I am not sure as to how I continue from here. Help would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!!

Please change the title to a description of the problem. Thank you.

" α+β=180∘ (we know because of Alternate (interior) angles) β + m∠ECA = 180∘ (we know this because angles on a straight line have to equal 180 degrees)"  ... and therefore $m\angle ECA = 180 - \beta = \alpha$.

An alternative (which is actually the same) could be to cant the figure in two along the AC line.  Lift the triangle ABC up off the paper and turn it upside down and lie it down on the pape aligning point C of triangle ABC with point A of triangle ADC and point A of tri ABC with point C of triangle ABC.  (Same figure but with triangle ABC upside down).  As $\alpha + \beta=180$ The line from D to C=A and from C=A to B is a straight line.  So we have a triangle.  It's isoceles.  So t $\theta = 47$.

You've made a good start. As you noted, $\alpha + \beta = 180^{\circ}$ and $\beta + \measuredangle ECA = 180^{\circ}$, so comparing these $2$ equations gives
$$\measuredangle ECA = \alpha$$
Since $\lvert CE\rvert = \lvert AB\rvert$, by construction, and of course $\lvert CA\rvert = \lvert AC\rvert$, then by $SAS$ (Side-Angle-Side), we get
$$\triangle CEA \cong \triangle ABC$$
Thus, we also have
$$\measuredangle CEA = \measuredangle ABC = 47^{\circ}, \;\; \lvert EA\rvert = \lvert BC\rvert = \lvert AD\rvert$$
This means that $\triangle ADC$ is isosceles, and therefore
$$\theta = \measuredangle ADE = \measuredangle CEA = 47^{\circ}$$

Note that another way to determine this, with just the original diagram, is to use the law of sines. In $\triangle ACD$, we get
$$\frac{\sin(\measuredangle ACD)}{\lvert AD\rvert} = \frac{\sin(\measuredangle ADC)}{\lvert AC\rvert} \;\;\to\;\; \frac{\sin(\beta)}{\lvert AD\rvert} = \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\lvert AC\rvert}$$
while using this law in $\triangle ABC$ gives that
$$\frac{\sin(\measuredangle BAC)}{\lvert BC\rvert} = \frac{\sin(\measuredangle ABC)}{\lvert AC\rvert} \;\;\to\;\; \frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\lvert BC\rvert} = \frac{\sin(47^{\circ})}{\lvert AC\rvert}$$
Since $\alpha + \beta = 180^{\circ}$, then $\sin(\beta) = \sin(\alpha)$, and it's given that $\lvert AD\rvert = \lvert BC\rvert$, so comparing the above $2$ sets of equations results in
$$\sin(\theta) = \sin(47^{\circ})$$
Thus, we have either that $\theta = 47^{\circ}$ or $\theta + 47^{\circ} = 180^{\circ}$. However, in the latter case, this gives
$$\theta + 47^{\circ} = \beta + \alpha = 180^{\circ} \;\;\to\;\; (\theta + \beta) + (47^{\circ} + \alpha) = 360^{\circ}$$
Since the internal angles in a triangle sum to $180^{\circ}$, we also get
$$(\theta + \beta + \measuredangle CAD) + (47^{\circ} + \alpha + \measuredangle ACB) = 360^{\circ}$$
Comparing these $2$ sets of equations gives that
$$\measuredangle CAD + \measuredangle ACB = 0^{\circ}$$
which is impossible in non-degenerate triangles. Thus, we get, as before, that $\theta = 47^{\circ}$.

Reflect $AD$ about $AC$ to $AD'$ so $CD' \parallel AB$, translate $AD'$ by $AB$ to $BD''$ then we have isosceles $CBD''$ and $\theta=47$.

Edit: adding a bit about the logic of solving this problem. If you're given angles summing to $180$ the situation is ripe for two things, either getting those angles on a single line as supplements (what your hint did) or getting a set of parallel lines going (what I did by reflection). Since you are given two equal sides, it seems an isosceles triangle or a parallelogram would be helpful. Your hint shortcuts the isosceles approach (extend $AB, CE$, they meet, draw at $B$ a segment $BE \parallel AC$ and by Thales you have $AB=CE$) and John then uses triangle congruence on the shared base to get the result. The other approach, building parallel lines, is ready-made for generating parallelograms, which is what I did by translation. Which then gave me isosceles triangles where I needed them. Both of these are natural solutions to the situation.
